# How to switch to camera view in After effects?

Tags: premiere, after-effects, camera

I'm unable to rotate my camera because I don't know how to switch to camera view.

Answer (score 1):

There's a camera drop-down at the bottom of the comp window. You can select the active camera there.

[image]

**Pro Tip:** Hitting the <kbd>escape</kbd> key will toggle between the two last used cameras.